# match array against string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, match

I'm reading a file using bufferedreader, so lets say i have

```
line = br.readLine();
```

I want to check if this line contains one of many possible strings (which i have in an array). I would like to be able to write something like:

```
while (!line.matches(stringArray) { // not sure how to write this conditional
  do something here;
  br.readLine();
}
```

I'm fairly new to programming and Java, am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy all values into a `Set<String>` and then use `contains()`:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList (stringArray));
while (!set.contains(line)) { ... }
```

[EDIT] If you want to find out if *a part of the line* contains a string from the set, you have to loop over the set. Replace `set.contains(line)` with a call to:

```
public boolean matches(Set<String> set, String line) {
    for (String check: set) {
        if (line.contains(check)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Adjust the check accordingly when you use regexp or a more complex method for matching.

[EDIT2] A third option is to concatenate the elements in the array in a huge regexp with `|`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("str1|str2|str3");

while (!p.matcher(line).find()) { // or matches for a whole-string match
    ...
}
```

This can be more cheap if you have many elements in the array since the regexp code will optimize the matching process.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong please, but doesnt this check to see if the array contains the line being read from the file, instead of checking if the line contains one of the strings from the array?

Comment: Regex is then dependent on the contents of the String array. Could be considered a security flaw, depending on what that condition is you are checking.

Comment: @Daniel: There is no information where that data comes from, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. I don't understand some of the syntax so I've got a bit of reading to do.

Comment: You could escape the literal strings with `Pattern.quote()` first.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what `stringArray` is. If it's a [`Collection`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) then fine. If it's a true array, you should make it a `Collection`. The `Collection` interface has a method called [`contains()`](http://bit.ly/2o9fix) that will determine if a given `Object` is in the `Collection`.

Simple way to turn an array into a `Collection`:

```
String tokens[] = { ... }
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(tokens);
```

The problem with a [`List`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is that lookup is expensive (technically linear or `O(n)`). A better bet is to use a [`Set`](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enAU314AU317&q=java.util.set+6&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=), which is unordered but has near-constant (`O(1)`) lookup. You can construct one like this:

From a `Collection`:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(stringList);
```

From an array:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
```

and then `set.contains(line)` will be a cheap operation.

**Edit:** Ok, I think your question wasn't clear. You want to see if the line contains any of the words in the array. What you want then is something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
Set<String> words = ... // construct this as per above
try {
  in = ...
  while ((String line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    for (String word : words) {
      if (line.contains(word)) [
        // do whatever
      }
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (in != null) { try { in.close(); } catch (Exception e) { } }
}
```

This is quite a crude check, which is used surprisingly open and tends to give annoying false positives on words like "scrap". For a more sophisticated solution you probably have to use regular expression and look for word boundaries:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\b)" + word + "(?=\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.find() {
  // word found
}
```

You will probably want to do this more efficiently (like not compiling the pattern with every line) but that's the basic tool to use.

Comment: Mind the security implications of the regex approach - depending on where the strings in the array come from, this might disrupt the regex and allow injection of arbitrary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `String.matches(regex)` function, what about creating a regular expression that matches any one of the strings in the string array? Something like

```
String regex = "*(";
for(int i; i < array.length-1; ++i)
  regex += array[i] + "|";
regex += array[array.length] + ")*";
while( line.matches(regex) )
{
  //. . . 
}
```

Comment: -1 This is error prone. Depending on the contents of the String array your regular expression changes. Could even be considered a security flaw.

Comment: The array was never stated to be a static array. How do you suggest implementing a regular expression that matches a dynamic array, that "does not change"?